# Make PHPDesktop work with Symfony3

Tags: symfony-2.8, symfony-3.2, phpdesktop

I've built a Symfony application that have to be run on Windows and I want to make it very simple to be installed. For this purpose, I found [PHPDesktop](https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop) very perfect but I can't make it work with Symfony3 allthough there is a wiki page that describe how to make it work with Symfony 2.6 any solution or link to tutorial that make this app works with Symfony3 or 2.8 is welcome.

Comment: What is the error? You may also try asking on PHP Desktop Forum.

Comment: It simply show blank page.

Comment: Without errors or code no one can really answer this

Comment: Thanks ! notice that an alternative answer I'm looking for is also a commercial version of PHPDesktop does it exist ?

Comment: You can enable debug console and see what logs say (404 errors maybe due to invalid routing configuration). See the Settings wiki page in phpdesktop. There is no commercial versoin of phpdesktop.